# binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type const T (template)

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

There are many problems solved already with similar issues but couldn't really found my exact problem. 
If you have any ideas kindly help here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

#include "Song.h"
#include "Inventory.h"
#include "SongSpec.h"


template <typename T>
void show(const T& item)
{
    std::cout << item << std::endl;    //line of mistake
}

template <typename T>
void show_all(const std::vector<T>& items)
{
    for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), show<T>);
}
```

If you need information about other classes let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Whatever `T` is, there exists no overload for `operator<<` takes a right-hand operand of this type. That's basically it. You need to implement such an overload.

Comment: There's not enough information in the original version of the question. If I use your `show_all` on (for example) a `std::vector<int>` it works just fine. The title suggests you do not have a stream insertion operator (operator <<) for the type with which you are using `show_all`.

Comment: @churill I did your way. Before it was showing the same error twice, now it is showing the error once. It means one of my classes was left without operator overloading ?